# Tycho cannot find requirement org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool

Tags: java, rcp, e4, eclipse-oxygen

I'm building my RCP application using Tycho. Now I upgraded to Oxygen and added the new repository to my target file. But when I compile using Tycho it gives following error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 10053 2018-03-01 10:06:50.866
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2018-03-01 10:06:50.867
!MESSAGE Software being installed: CR-IT_client 1.0.0 (CR-IT_client_ID 1.0.0)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2018-03-01 10:06:50.868
!MESSAGE Missing requirement: Project 1.0.0 (Project_ID 1.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool [1.2.51.v20171122-1403]' but it could not be found
```

The dependency is in my target file like:

```
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool" version="0.0.0"/>
```

And I use following repositories in my target file:

```
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/1.5.0/repository/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/snapshot/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/incubation/snapshot/"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/snapshots/latest/repository/"/>
```

This fails in my tycho repository project. My Plugin project compiles without any issue.

The full error looks like:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:1.1.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project eclipse-repository: Installation of product Project_ID for environment win32/win32/x86_64 failed: Call to p2 director application failed with exit code 13
```

Can someone help me with this error? So that I can build my application using tycho again.

Full target file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="0.0"?>
<target name="eclipse oxygen">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeMode="planner" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="ca.odell.glazedlists" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="com.google.gson" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="com.google.guava" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="com.ibm.icu" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="com.jcraft.jsch" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="java_cup.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.activation" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.annotation" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.inject" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.mail" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.servlet" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.xml" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.ant" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.css" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.util" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.util.gui" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.codec" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.collections" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.io" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.jxpath" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.lang" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.lang3" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.logging" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.net" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.felix.gogo.command" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.felix.scr" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.log4j" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.lucene.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.poi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.xalan" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.xerces" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.xml.resolver" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.xml.serializer" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ant.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.compare.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.jobs" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.net" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.variables" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.debug.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.edit" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.app" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.region" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.security" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.util" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.help" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.annotation" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jem.util" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface.text" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.poi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.pshelf" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.services" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.util" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.team.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.text" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.browser" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.console" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.editors" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.forms" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.ide" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.views" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.win32" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wb.swing.FormLayout.lib" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.emf" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.environment" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.sse.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.validation" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xsd" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.sat4j.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.sat4j.pb" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.tukaani.xz" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.w3c.css.sac" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.w3c.dom.events" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.w3c.dom.smil" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.w3c.dom.svg" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.core.patch.feature.group" verion="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>

            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/1.5.0/repository/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/snapshot/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/incubation/snapshot/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/snapshots/latest/repository/"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

My Required-bundles from the Manifest file looks like:

```
javax.inject;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.11.1",
 org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.104.2",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="1.1.100",
 org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.11.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.3.1",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.pshelf;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.commands;bundle-version="0.11.100",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 ca.odell.glazedlists;bundle-version="1.9.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher;bundle-version="1.3.200",
 org.eclipse.rcp;bundle-version="4.6.2",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core;bundle-version="2.4.100",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine;bundle-version="2.4.100",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations;bundle-version="2.4.200",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository;bundle-version="1.2.300",
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.poi;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.apache.poi;bundle-version="3.9.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,
 org.eclipse.osgi.services
```

Comment: Looks like you are specifying an exact version for `org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool` somwhere. The version in Oxygen is different so you need to relax the version requirement.

Comment: I added the full target file. And I cannot fine an exact version in there.

Comment: More likely to be in a MANIFEST.MF - probably for 'Project_ID'

Comment: Added required-bundles of manifest file to the question

Comment: Ok found it. Eclipse only knows the version 1.2.51.v20171122-1403 of org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool. When I add it back to the product file it only gives me this version. How can I update this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the issue by removing all the org.eclipse.jdt.* dependencies from the product file.